# How Can I Restrict the Usage of an F# Union Type to A Particular Option

Tags: generics, f#, algebraic-data-types, discriminated-union

I am teaching myself F#--For Fun and Profit!--and, while I've made some strides, I have run into a stumbling block with usage of algebraic types.  Below is a JSON type that I coded to serialize an arbitrary JSON structure to a string.  I am open to subjective comments on it's design and efficiency, of course, but I am mainly focussed on line 7:

```
type JSON =
    | JString of string
    | JNumber of decimal
    | JBool   of bool
    | JNull
    | JArray  of JSON list
    | JObject of Map< JSON, JSON >
with
    member this.Serialize  =
        let rec serialize ( element : JSON ) =
            match element with
            | JString str ->
                "\"" + str + "\""
            | JNumber num ->
                num.ToString()
            | JBool   bln -> 
                bln.ToString().ToLower()
            | JNull       ->
                "null"
            | JArray  ary ->
                "[" + String.concat "," ( List.map serialize ary ) + "]"
            | JObject obj -> 
                "{" + (
                    Map.fold (
                        fun state key value ->
                            state + ( match state with "" -> "" | _ -> "," )
                                  + ( serialize key ) 
                                  + ":" 
                                  + ( serialize value ) ) "" obj ) + "}"
        serialize( this )
```

Anyone familiar with JSON knows that a key/value pair of a JSON object should be keyed on a string, not just any JSON element/value.  Is there a way to further restrict the first type parameter of the Map?  These, of course, do not work:

```
type JSON =
    ... elided ...
    | JObject of Map< JSON.JString, JSON >
```

...

```
type JSON =
    ... elided ...
    | JObject of Map< JString, JSON >
```

...

```
type JSON =
    ... elided ...
    | JObject of Map< string, JSON >
```

Thanks.

Comment: `JObject of Map< string, JSON >` works on my computer...

Comment: I'll look into using string as the key again.  I was having issues in the serialization of JObject with that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing another case identifier from within a discriminated union is not possible. From [Discriminated Unions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions),

> ## Syntax
>
> [ attributes ]
>
> type [accessibility-modifier] type-name =
>
> | case-identifier1 [of [ fieldname1 : ] type1 [ * [ fieldname2 : ] type2 ...]
>
> | case-identifier2 [of [fieldname3 : ] type3 [ * [ fieldname4 : ] type4 ...]
>
> [ member-list ]

This means that each case identifier must be `of` some type. A case identifier itself is **not** a type.

One way you could achieve the same functionality is by breaking the discriminated union into multiple discriminated unions:

```
type JSONKey =
| JString of string

type JSONValue =
| JString of string
| JNumber of decimal
| JBool of bool
| JNull
| JArray of JSONValue list
| JObject of Map<JSONKey, JSONValue>
```

and then defining `JSON` as:

```
type JSON = Map<JSONKey, JSONValue>
```

Then, `serialize` would need to be changed to `let rec serialize ( element : JSONValue )`
and
`serialize( this )` would need to be changed to `serialize( JObject this )`.

---

As **@Ringil** mentioned, `Map<string, JSON>` will work in this situation, but this is not too extensible/restrictive.

Comment: The case identifier NOT being a type is a distinction that was lost on me at this juncture.  I was more or less thinking of them as subtypes.  I appreciate the clarification and suggested solution.